# External iWidget causing refresh of IBM Connections page

Tags: widget, ibm-connections

I have added 3rd party widgets to IBM Connections (both 4.0 and 4.5) in homepage and communities and they cause the page to go into a redirect loop after the widgets finish loading.

I have tried many different security and widget settings without being able to remove this behaviour.

Symptoms 
- When a third party widget loads on the page, the page goes into a redirect loop. 
- In Homepage - it gets a 302 redirect to "GET /homepage/web/authredirect.action HTTP/1.1"
- In Communities - it gets a 302 redirect to "GET /communities/service/html/login HTTP/1.1"

In both cases the page it is redirected to finds that you are actually authenticated and you are redirected back to the original page.

Has anyone experienced anything like this before and knows how to fix it?

Comment: have you loaded this in Firefox and used the built-in Web Console to persist the network and console?  it'd give you a lot of insight as to why.

Comment: These logs (as well a a Fiddler Trace) are inconclusive at best. THe only thing I thought could be an issue was a problem with cre$.iruntime (an IBM javascript library as far as I could work out). These same widgets are in many other IBM Connections environments without there being any issue so I feel like it must be a Connections or WAS configuration issue however I have been unable to track it down as there are many of these such configuration options.

Comment: I'd have to see the Firebug Console's Net Panel to help.  It sounds like you may have an SSL issue where you don't have the Signer Certificate for your HTTP Server in the CellDefaultTrustStore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this happen when the iWidget uses Dojo to perform a request with **handleAs="json"**.
Instead, use **handleAs="text"**, and then use dojo.fromJson(dataStr) to parse the string into a json object.

For example, the following caused a reload issue for me:

```
var xhrArgs =
{
    url:'/MyServlet',
    content:{Id:this.userId},
    handleAs:"json",
    load:dojo.hitch(this,function(jsonObj){
        console.log("json",jsonObj);
    }),
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
};
dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
```

Changing the handleAs to 'text' with a dojo.fromJson() call solved the problem:

```
var xhrArgs =
{       
    url:'/MyServlet',
    content:{Id:this.userId},
    handleAs:"text",
    load:dojo.hitch(this,function(data){
        var jsonObj = dojo.fromJson(data);
        console.log("json",jsonObj);
    }),
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
};
dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
```